# what is the 2nd parameter in cv2.normalize() for

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I want to normalize a image with `cv2.normalize()` as follow

```
import cv2
original_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/test.jpg")
normalized_image = cv2.normalize(original_image, alpha=0.0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

This works fine with opencv2 (in Python). But with opencv3, an error of

> TypeError: Required argument 'dst' (pos 2) not found

is thrown and I has to passed in another parameter

```
arr = np.array([])
normalized_image = cv2.normalize(original_image, arr, alpha=0.0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) it seems to be the destination, but interestingly the result is stored in `normalized_image`, and `arr` is `[]` after that.

So what is this second parameter for in opencv3 (Python) ?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as well:

```
import cv2
original_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/test.jpg")
normalized_image = cv2.normalize(original_image,None)
```

The array is store in normalized_image

Comment: In Python 3.7, for me at least, this works and using `dst=some_array` does not.

Answer (score 2):

The returned value of `cv2.normalize` *will* depend on the types of both `src` and `dst` (if provided). At first, it appeared that calling `cv2.normalize(src, dst)` would not work as expected, *i.e.* have `dst` unchanged. However, this is not totally true. Let's go through a toy example:

```
>>> src = np.array([[1,2,4], [3,2,1], [-1,2,6]]).astype(float)
>>> src.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Normalizing between `0` and `1`, we are expecting to get:

```
>>> (src - src.min()) / (src.max() - src.min())
array([[0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.71428571],
       [0.57142857, 0.42857143, 0.28571429],
       [0.        , 0.42857143, 1.        ]])
```

now with OpenCV:

```
>>> cv2.normalize(src, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) # pythonic way
array([[0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.71428571],
       [0.57142857, 0.42857143, 0.28571429],
       [0.        , 0.42857143, 1.        ]])


>>> dst = np.zeros_like(src)
>>> cv2.normalize(src, dst, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) # move to dst
>>> dst
array([[0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.71428571],
       [0.57142857, 0.42857143, 0.28571429],
       [0.        , 0.42857143, 1.        ]])
```

*Note `dst.dtype` is `dtype('float64')`.*

---

However in the following two case, the normalized array won't get moved to `dst`:

1. If `dst` as a different shape to `src`, `dst` will stay unchanged:

   ```
   >>> dst = np.array([])
   >>> cv2.normalize(src, dst, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
   array([[0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.71428571],
          [0.57142857, 0.42857143, 0.28571429],
          [0.        , 0.42857143, 1.        ]])
   >>> dst
   array([], dtype=float64)
   ```

   As you can see, `cv2.normalize` will return the correct normalized array, but won't move the data to `dst`.
2. If `dst` as a different type to `src`:

   ```
   >>> dst = np.zeros_like(src).astype(int)
   >>> cv2.normalize(src, dst, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
   <UMat 0x7f578300c510>
   >>> dst
   array([[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]])
   ```

---

All in all, it seems safer to work with the returned value rather that with `dst`, which might not get changed to `src`-normalized depending on the circumstances.

Here is a related topic where you can read more about `cv2.normalize`: [*Normalizing while keeping the value of 'dst' as an empty array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247508/normalizing-while-keeping-the-value-of-dst-as-an-empty-array/55247665).

Comment: I think your answer is correct, and I also think that `dst` argument is from the  `c++` style.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find [here in the docu](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) dst describes the destination image for your normalize operation. Seems that the signature of the function was changed. Before the destination image was returned, in opencv3 it will be definied as a parameter. 
So this shall work from my point of viewn (untested) :

```
arr = np.array([])
cv2.normalize(original_image, normalized_image, arr, 
    alpha=0.0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Comment: I may be testing it wrong, but this does not work. The normalized image is not assigned to `arr`, and it remains a blank array. The more pythonic `normalized_image = cv2.normalize(original_image,None)` does work.

Answer (score 1):

```html
arr = np.array([])
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], mask, self.bins,
                            [0, 180, 0, 256, 0, 256])
hist = cv2.normalize(hist,arr).flatten()
```

works for me